# Is visualization OK on laptops with Optimus+Bumblebee?

Tags: ros, nvidia, bumblebee

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm mostly interested in whether rviz will work if I install [bumblebee](https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee) on a laptop that has NVIDIA graphics and Optimus (in which the NV card sends its output through the Intel graphics hardware, which sends everything out to the display).

Has anyone tried this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10397/is-visualization-ok-on-laptops-with-optimus+bumblebee?/) by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) on ROS Answers with karma: 438 on 2011-06-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-25**:
I know some colleagues that have an Optimus laptop on linux and they are NOT happy. I would stay away from that for now, although the latest I have heard is a couple of weeks old. Whatever you do: Use the latest bumblebee, there was a bug deleting /usr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Optimus on the TurtleBot laptops does not currently work.  The Nvidia card cannot be used.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My T410 Thinkpad has an optimus card. In order to get the NV drivers working under Ubuntu 10.10 I had to disable the Intel graphics in BIOS, after which everything worked fine (unfortunately, you don't get the battery savings that optmius integrated graphics would offer). I've had no problems with rviz + kinect point clouds on my laptop.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1